# Basemap Gallery Error - ESRI JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm getting an error when trying to switch basemaps in [my application](https://www.marioncountyfl.org/gisproduction/zoning/index.html)(right now only works in IE9).

**TypeError: Unable to get value of the property '_basemapGalleryLayerType': object is null or undefined**

I'm using standard code provided in the ESRI samples. The full code is a mashup of various samples, so my error may be in the order I've placed things. However, I've tried reordering the code and haven't had any luck.

When I remove `mapReady` from the `dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", mapReady);` listener, the basemap gallery works, however it causes my initial basemap to fail and the mapReady function to fail as well (obviously). There is no link that I can determine between the initial basemaps and my mapReady function so I'm not sure what the deal is there...

Also, if I clear the browser cache the entire app will work, 1 time only, then on refresh, it fails as described above. Very inconsistent behavior.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function createBasemapGallery() {
        // Add the basemap gallery
        basemapGallery = new esri.dijit.BasemapGallery({showArcGISBasemaps: true, map: globals.map}, "basemapGallery");
        basemapGallery.startup(); 
        dojo.connect(basemapGallery, "onError", function(msg) {console.log(msg)});
      }
```

Then, inside `init()` function and **after** creating the map:

```
createBasemapGallery();
dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(theMap) {
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', map, map.resize);
}
```

Then on the HTML:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="width:380px; height:280px; overflow:auto;">
    <div id="basemapGallery" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this work for you in general, or were you able to edit my code and get the app to work?